# Android Battery Level Notification & after 5 mins shutdown/Power Off the Device

Tags: android, battery

I have Android application which is Sales Rep application.When he using the app first need to show the notification like your battery level is 10%  ..., then after 2 minutes if he doesn't plug the power , it automatically need to shut down the device.

I have created like this

```
     public class BatteryLevelActivity extends BroadcastReceiver{

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int level = intent.getIntExtra("level", 0);  
            Toast.makeText(context, "Battery Level is "+level+"%", Toast.LENGTH_LONG) ;

    }
}
```

And My androidManifest File

```
       <receiver android:name=".service.BatteryLevelActivity">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And Calling place i did like this

```
     batteryLevelReceiver = new BatteryLevelReceiver();
    IntentFilter intentFilter1 = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    intentFilter1.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW);
    registerReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver, intentFilter1);
```

It go to  `BatteryLevelReceiver` class. I really don't know How to check `power is plugged or not` && how to power off automatically after showing the notification ?

Please anybody help me on this ...

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check that the device is plugged in or not you can try this stuff,

```
public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
        Intent intent = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
        int plugged = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
        return plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC || plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
    }
```

For shutting down device [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745523/programmatically-switching-off-android-phone) is a thread that you will like to check and for checking the plugged in status already posted the method from [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283491/android-check-if-device-is-plugged-in) thread.

Comment: No.Still not showing Shutdown screen/dialog. I did ` PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
   PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
   wl.acquire();`

Comment: You can checkout [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756768/turn-off-screen-on-android)

Answer (score 2):

Once you have determined how to detect the level of power in the battery then I'd recommend instead of throwing a notification to the bar, just send the shutdown command to the device, this will internally generate the shutdown dialog.

**Update**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SHUTDOWN

Answer (score 1):

Check for  ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED , BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB or BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC
Hope this will help : [How to detect power connected state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267161/how-to-detect-power-connected-state)