# Determine if power/usb cable is plugged in Android device

Tags: android, power-management

I need to determine whether the power cable (usb cable) is plugged in. The solutions on SO all use a broadcast receiver to receive a power change event. The problem with this approach is that the cable may already be plugged in before my receiver gets registered, in which case no change event will get fired. I need a way to determine whether the cable is plugged in without relying upon a broadcast receiver.

Comment: Covered here: http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html#DetermineChargeState  Because it's a sticky intent, you don't need to register a BroadcastReceiver..... the current battery status intent is returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283491/android-check-if-device-is-plugged-in).

```
public class PowerUtil {
    public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
        Intent intent = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
        int plugged = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
        return plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC || plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
    }
}
```