# check USB attached or not in a button click android

Tags: android, usb, broadcasting

In a button click, I want to check any USB is connected to the device or not. If connected then some action(may be a toast).When a button is clicked a broadcast for checking if USB is connected or not.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about all the censorious but here how you test if your device is charging:

```
public class PowerUtil {
    public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
        Intent intent = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
        int plugged = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
        return plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC || plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
    }
}
```

Found at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7156252/1129332) question.

**Edit:** Using [UsbManager.getDeviceList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.html#getDeviceList%28%29) you get all the connected devices. So if size is 0 no USB is connected.

Comment: @Jerry See my edit. Found it using a hint from Dharmesh answer