# How to get battery usage since full charge android programmatically?

Tags: android

[image]

I want to get battery uses for each app after a full charge.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge in Android you will not be possible to do this, As per the developer documentation you can only Monitor changes in the Battery state

https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring

Answer (score 0):

You can use these both answers for your issue:

First the way that you can get battery information or when fully charged in:

[answer of the get fully charged notif](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/20451)

Second  the way you can get information of battery usages in a file :

[get battery usage of other apps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32689345/10608556)

Update me in comments