# Android : How to use registerReceiver in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to perform some task when I get `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` intent, i'm using following code to check if device is plugged in but I get *method is undefined for the type BootReceiver* at `registerReceiver`. Can anyone find the solution? here is what i'm doing.

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {

    if(isCharging())
    doSomething();  //something to perform after boot if plugged in

        }



        public boolean isCharging() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    Intent batteryStatus = registerReceiver(null, filter); //getting error here

    boolean strState;

    int chargeState = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);

    switch (chargeState) {
        case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING:
        case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL:
            strState = true;
            break;
        default:
            strState = false;
    }
    return strState;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED))`. This will return an `Intent` that has extras defined on `BatteryManager` to let you know if it is plugged in or not.

This works because `Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` is a sticky broadcast.

Answer picked from [Check if device is plugged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283491/android-check-if-device-is-plugged-in) by CommonsWare

**UPDATE:**
Please call `context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));` this method is defined in context

Comment: i'm already using it, check the code in question once again, I get same error